# RPROMPT not showing on initial prompt

Tags: zsh, zsh-zle

I'm seeing a strange issue when trying to use RPROMPT to configure my zsh prompt. I'm not using oh-my-zsh or any other plugin manager. Here is my `.zshrc` file:

```
function zle-line-init {
  RPROMPT="foo"
  zle reset-prompt
}

zle -N zle-line-init
```

However, on the *first* prompt (when opening a new shell, or new tmux window/pane), the `foo` doesn't show. (I then press enter and the RPROMPT shows for the new prompt.)

Why doesn't it show on the first one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `zsh` first prints the initial prompt, `RPROMPT` is not set so the feature is disabled. Just set `RPROMPT` to anything outside the `zle-line-init` function.